# Find middle point between distances in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So in photoshop if I have a picture of a head, and I want to make a line from the top of the head to the bottom of the head, how do I display the middle of that line? The ruler tool doesn't have an option to mark the center.

Is there any program that has that simple option? I just want to draw a line and have it mark the center.

EDIT: All great suggestions. Additionally, you can use Marquee tool and just press ctrl + t after you draw a box and it will show the center temporarily.

Comment: Do you simply want to know where the center is or are you seeking some sort of auto-indicator which would be part of the image itself, such as CAD dimensioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use following techique in Illustrator and Photoshop:

Draw a straight path, copy the path, and rotate by 90 degrees. Since the rotation pivot is by default in the middle you get a cross that achieves exactly what you want. This has the advantage of also working for arbitrary angles.  More importantly this can be recorded as a action and applied to many paths at once with just a keypress if you find yourself doing this alot.

Also if i remember correctly (need to check when i go home atleast it works for rotation) when you measure a distance it puts that value in the move dialog you can then divide by 2 or even 3, to get a precice move from end to any division.

Answer (score 1):

There's also another simple way to find out the center whether it is from top to bottom, from left to right or vice versa.
All you need to do is pull out a ruler and just drag it over your working area slowly, and when you pass over the center of the working area you'll see a slight change in the movement and feel like it sticks to the center of the space for a just a small while. It'll be something like a staggered movement of the ruler near the center of the work space.
Now this is the most simple method that you can use but it needs quite a keen observation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the line you want to find the center of is a vertical line aligned to the middle of the image. What I would do in the situation you are in is create a horizontal line perpendicular to the vertical line previously created, and align it to the center of the vertical line. The point where the lines cross is the exact centre of the vertical line. Simple enough.

Answer (score -1):

Set your rulers to percent.  By placing your mouse at 50% you will have the center.